# Images are getting resized in Print Preview

Tags: html, css, print-css

I have several images(not background images) on my webpage, When I see the Print Preview at 100% scale, images looks fine, but My problem is that when I do a print prview with Shrink to fit scale, all the images are coming smaller than the actual size. I have not supplied any width or height attribute on IMG tag so I assume that in print preview it will load as they appear on screen. I have used below css for print media for IMG but it did not work

```
img {max-width:100%; }
```

I am expecting the same image dimension in Shrink to fit and 100% scale.

Is this possible? am I missing something in print css?  Please advice.

Comment: use print specific `@media queries` or `media="print"` stylesheet

Comment: @Mr.Alien - I already have one print css with the above rule also in it.

Comment: don't use `max-width` try using only `width`

Answer (score 5):

While working on my project, when I needed to get the original size of image in print preview, I had to use `!important.` Otherwise, it wouldn't overwrite the style defined initially for the image on the page.

I also had to modify the height of image containers:

```
@media print {
      .logo-container,
      .img-wrapper,
      img {
        max-height: none !important;
        height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your images inside 'container' or 'div' etc? you should create print style for them also not just for the img elements.

I would suggest to use the same style on your elements both for screen and print , like so(this is my print.css):

```
/*How they look like on the print preview*/
@media print {
    #poweredbyLogo{
        width:213px;
    }
    #logoframe{
        height:80px;
        margin-top:6px;
    }

    .space{
        padding-left:20px;
    }

    .col-md-6.a1{
        background-color: #0000f6!important;
    }
    .col-md-6.a2{
        background-color: #d3d3d3!important;
    }
}
/*How they look like on the screen*/
@media screen {
    #poweredbyLogo{
        width:47%;
    }

    #logoframe{
        height:80px;
        margin-top:6px;
    }

    .space{
        padding-left:20px;
    }
}
```

Hope helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this.

```
<img class="application-logo res-media" width="65" height="65">


@media screen {
    .application-logo{
        width: 65px !important;
        height: 60px !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 25px;
    }
}

@media print {
    .application-logo, ._imgcont, img {
        max-height: none !important;
        height: 65px !important;
    }
}
```